# VB.net JSON DeserializeObject error BC30203

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization

I'm using the Newtonsoft.dll to create a Settings.json file. I have a class that represents the settings, which i serialize upon saving and deserialize when loading the application. Everything is working great and fast except for one thing.

The settings class contains an .NET object called `SpeechSynthesizer`. When the settings is deserialized i get an `BC30203: Identifier expected` at the `Voice` child object of the `SpeechSynthesizer`. This causes the deserialized returning the default `Voice' (Anna) settings instead of the saved one's (Serializing the setting object does work as it should) The settings of the object before this child object are properly deserialized.

The JSON:

```
  {      ......
  "Speech": {
    "State": 0,
    "Rate": -3,
    "Volume": 67,
    "Voice": {
      "Gender": 1,
      "Age": 30,
      "Name": "IVONA 2 Ruben",
      "Culture": "nl-NL",
      "Id": "IVONA 2 Voice Ruben22",
      "Description": "IVONA 2 Ruben - Dutch male voice [22kHz]",
      "SupportedAudioFormats": [],
      "AdditionalInfo": {
        "Language": "413",
        "Name": "IVONA 2 Ruben",
        "Age": "Adult",
        "Gender": "Male",
        "Vendor": "IVONA Software Sp. z o. o."
      }
    }
  }
```

Deserialize Code:

`Return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Settings)(File.ReadAllText(settingsfile))`

Serialize Code:

```
    Using _file As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(SettingFilePath)
        Dim serializer As New JsonSerializer()
        serializer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        serializer.Serialize(_file, Me)
    End Using
```

Settings Code:

```
''' <summary>
''' Get or Set the properties that is used for the SpeechSynthesizer
''' </summary>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Property Speech As SpeechSynthesizer
```

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNU2i.png)

Comment: Never use this, but the [`Voice`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.voice(v=vs.110).aspx) property is read only, so you may have to just save the voice name in your settings and use `SpeechSynthesizer.SelectVoice` with the name, instead of trying to serialize the `SpeechSynthesizer` instance.

Comment: Mark, Thx for your reply. Id never occured to me it was a `ReadOnly` object. I now save the `VoiceInfo` as a seperate setting, loading it via `.SelectVoice` at startup. Thx! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question was, as Mark pointed out, the object was `ReadOnly` Meaning it couldn't `Deserialize` during application startup `Deserializing`

The work arround is by adding a extra setting i called `SelectedVoice` As a string. Upon startup i use the `SpeechSynthesizer.SelectVoice(_Settings.SelectedVoice)` To load the voice that was set by the user.